Error while Implementing CICD pipepline using GITHUB Actions for CloudHub deployment
I'm trying to implement CICD pipeline using Github Actions,
in deployment command I'm passing the SECRET_KEY in below format,
-Dmule.secret.key=${{ env.SECRET_KEY }}
And my SECRET_KEY is defined in "Secrets" in github setting and it  contains '$' , suppose my key is "hello$world". then the value secret.key is getting populated as "hello$" only, the string after $ is getting truncated.
Can anyone please help me with this?
I tried passing the value for -Dmule.secret.key = ${ env.SECRET_KEY } but this didn't work

Where are you seeing the value is truncated? In GitHub or in Mule? How is that expression used in GitHub Actions? Provide a [mre].
